# Regular Expressions: Replace list of hash characters with ol tag

Tags: php

Let me begin with: I guess I'm bad with regular expression. Really. In the last 4 days I tried to figure out how to replace the following format:

```
 # Item number 1
 # Item number 2
 # Item number 3
```

and so on, with:

```
<ol>
   <li>Item number 1</li>
   <li>Item number 2</li>
   <li>Item number 3</li>
</ol>
```

and so on. Originally I wanted to replace `/^\s\d\.\s/mi` with `<li>`, but I gave up really fast because it was even more complicated.

So I tried to run a loop, with `preg_match_all`, to get all possible groups, and replace them into an html tags. but I did something wrong, and I don't know what. Any help will be very appreciated.

That's my code (`$_POST` Request processed with XHR):

```
$innerhtml = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['innerhtml']));
$br_nums   = '<br>';
if (strstr($innerhtml, PHP_EOL)) {
    $innerhtml = preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n/", $br_nums, $innerhtml);
}

preg_match_all('/^\s[\#\.]\s.*/mi', $innerhtml, $outmatch);
if (isset($outmatch[0])) {
    $origin_outmatc = $outmatch[0];
    $outmatch       = implode('[\r\n]', $outmatch[0]);
    $original_match = $outmatch;
    $outmatch       = explode('<br>', $outmatch);

    foreach ($outmatch as $key => $match) {
        if (preg_match('/^\<br\>/i', $match) || preg_match('/^\<br\>\[\\r\\n\]/i', $match)) {
            $match = str_replace('<br>', '', preg_replace('/^\[\\r\\n\]/i', '', $match));
        }
    }

    $full_ol = '';
    foreach($outmatch as $ol) {
        $full_ol .= '<ol>';
        $ol       = preg_replace('/^\s[\#\.]\s/', '<li>', str_replace('[\r\n]', '</li>', $ol));
        $full_ol .= $ol;
        $full_ol .= '</ol>';
    }

    $full_ol = str_replace(' # ', '<li>', preg_replace('/(?:$|)\<(?!\/li\>)\/ol\>/i', '</li></ol>', $full_ol));
    $full_ol = preg_replace('/(?:|^)\<ol\>[\r\n]\<\/li\>/i', '<ol>', $full_ol);

    $full_ol = explode('<ol>', $full_ol);
    foreach ($full_ol as $key => $list) {
        if (empty($list)) {
            unset($full_ol[$key]);
            $full_ol = array_values($full_ol);
        }
    }

    foreach ($full_ol as $key => $list) {
        $full_ol[$key] = '<ol>' . $list;
    }

    $original_match = str_replace('<br>', '+SPLIT_HERE+<br>', str_replace('[\r\n]', "\r\n", $original_match));
    $original_match = explode('+SPLIT_HERE+', $original_match);

    foreach ($original_match as $key => $possible_match) {
        if (!preg_match('/^\s\#\s/mi', $possible_match)) {
            unset($original_match[$key]);
            $original_match = array_values($original_match);
        }
    }

    foreach ($full_ol as $key => $possible_match) {
        if (preg_match('/^\<ol\>\<\/li\>\<\/ol\>$/i', $possible_match)) {
            unset($full_ol[$key]);
            $full_ol = array_values($full_ol);
        }
    }

    // Preview
    var_dump($original_match, $full_ol);

    // Replace original with html version
    $innerhtml = str_replace($original_match, $full_ol, $innerhtml);
}
```

Please, guide me - How can I do it better (or at least do it right)? I'm frustrated... Thanks.

Comment: try to use `/\s*#{1}\s*(.*)\n/` and build your ol list with a `foreach`

Comment: @Sysix can you show me example how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work. tested with [phptester.net](http://phptester.net/).

it's documented, if you have any questions you can command :)

```
<?php

$innerhtml = "
Hallo 123,

this is a little test

 # jeah
 # huhu
 # third

 line beetween?

 # okay lets do this again
 # second
 # final

 what about u?
";

$br_nums   = '<br>';

// with that code it is not working. because double line breaks means normaly <p>
// if (strstr($innerhtml, PHP_EOL)) {
//     $innerhtml = preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n/", $br_nums, $innerhtml);
// }

preg_match_all('/\s*#{1}\s*(.*)\n/', $innerhtml . "\n", $matches); // for last line matching

$olStarted = false;

if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $x => $match) {
        $replace = '';

        // start the ol, if is not started already
        if (!$olStarted) {
            $replace .= '<ol>';
            $olStarted = true;
        }

        // build li 
        $replace .= '<li>' . $match . '</li>';

        // end ol when of them is true
        //
        // 1* no next list item is there
        // 2* next list item is there, but a line breaks are between them
        if(
            !isset($matches[0][$x + 1]) || // 1*
            strpos($matches[0][$x + 1], "\n") === 1 // 2*
        ) {
           $replace .= '</ol>';
           $olStarted = false;
        }

        // actually replace the line
        $innerhtml = str_replace($matches[0][$x], $replace, $innerhtml);
    }
}

var_dump($innerhtml);
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression to match `# Item number 1` is:

```
\s*[#]\s+[iI][tT][eE][mM]\s+[nN][uU][mM][bB][eE][rR]\s+\[0-9]+\s*
```

This means:

```
(0+ spaces)#(1+ spaces)Item(1+ spaces)number(1+ spaces)123(0+ spaces)
```

And example would be: `"    #   Item number 12  "`

If a text matches this pattern, just match the next pattern:

```
[iI][tT][eE][mM]\s+[nN][uU][mM][bB][eE][rR]\s+\[0-9]+\s*
```

With the match you can get the index start of the matching string. Substring from `Match.Index` to `Length` of string and you will have this value:

```
Item number 1
```

P.D.

If `"Item"` can vary to be any string, just write `"\w+"` instead of `"[iI][tT][eE][mM]"`. The same applies for `"number"`.

Second way:

Match the main pattern:

```
\s*[#]\s+[iI][tT][eE][mM]\s+[nN][uU][mM][bB][eE][rR]\s+\[0-9]+\s*
```

When match is found, match this next pattern:

```
\s*[#]\s+
```

Now substring `"# item number 2"` from `Match.Value.Length` to `Length - Match.Value.Length` of String. In this case, substring from 2 to `"# item number 2"` length - `Match.Value.Length`.

Comment: I want to match ` # text` and not `# text`

Comment: Please, read the full answer first since I put it in there. If "Item" is a variable string, just type "\w+".

Comment: I process the request using XHR. The conversion (my bad) and match (etc) I do using PHP...

Comment: So let me clarify if your question is this:

You get a response form a request and returns you some value. In this value you want to find a text like this: "# text text 1".
Once you find this string pattern, you replace it with "<li>text text 1</li>".

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes (but with \s before the #)

Comment: @natanelg97 The pattern in my answer just matches what you asked for. It "Item" and "number" are variable strings, just change them to "\w+":

´\s*[#]\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+[0-9]+\s*´

This will match " # text text 1" or "#    text text  2   " or "    # text    text     3  ", etc(:

Comment: and what about ` # another item`

Comment: @Sysix \w+ is match for "anyText". Define what do you mean by 'another'. If another is a mix of Word+Number+Symbols, etc.
If 'another' is just a String, \w+ is a match for another, other, any thing that is text

Comment: my example was not the best.. you only match 2 string with a number.. between maybe spaces. But you don't match like `# that a command "curl --fail"` or other complex strings

Comment: @Sysix then it's just matter of changing \w for .